# Session Cookies intermittently missing from request on IE/chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, httprequest, session-cookies, fiddler, jsessionid

We are using JSP/servlets on tomcat on the server side. On the client side, we have IE and a desktop client in .NET with WebControl embedded. While browsing out site, users are loosing server sessions randomly between requests both in IE and .NET clients. This also seems to happen while using chrome, so its not a IE specific issue. When we view the HTTP requests through fiddler, we find that on a random request the JSESSIONID cookie is not being sent to the server, which results in the session timeout custom error. This happens consistently only on few of our users, while others work fine. One user especially times out a of times.

Could this be malware or some antivirus deleting the cookie. Or some malware on their systems?
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to know. Can you reproduce your case? Did you try? if you try without success, tell us where you didn't succeed to reproduce the problem? Can you add logs (pcap files)?

Comment: You should post a Fiddler SAZ File and we can look for cases where the server sends an errant Set-Cookie header that expires the cookie. There are many possible causes of this issue for IE but if it also affects Chrome, then the problem is almost certainly the server.